# What is the relationship between "Hochzeit" and "Hochmut?"

Tags: meaning, etymology, noun, prefix

As I understand it, *Hochzeit* means "wedding", and *Hochmut* means "pride", while *hoch* means "high".

Often, words with a common shared prefix are at least somewhat similar in meaning. But I can't relate *Hochzeit* and *Hochmut* to each other, nor can I relate either of them to the prefix *hoch-*. Why the disconnect?

Comment: Why do you assume there's a specific connection between these words? Is there a certain context? Not every word with the same prefix is related except that they have the same prefix. In this case the only connection may be they each reflect some elevated or outstanding extreme condition of the root words.

Comment: @Kevin: See Ansgar's answer. It is a good one. Even your comment, "each reflect some elevated or outstanding extreme condition of the root words" is quite a good answer.

Comment: I hope you got what you're looking for. :-) Although this principle can apply in most cases, be aware that words do change meanings and usage over time, and sometimes a whole new word and meaning can result that gets away from the individual roots.

Comment: @Kevin: "words do change meanings and usage over time, and sometimes a whole new word and meaning can result that gets away from the individual roots." That's what I'm looking to explore on this site.

Comment: @Kevin: See in particular the last part of the question, "not can I relate either of them to the prefix hoch". The latter is clearly possible, and for me that's the main point of the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both relate to *hoch*, although not quite literally. A wedding is a *high time*, a time of great joy; and *Hochmut* is a high (nowadays usually: too high) self-esteem. *Mut* means courage, but there is a older meaning (cf. *Gemüt*) that can be translated as *frame of mind*.

Comment: OK, "Hochzeit" or "high time" has a connection, although tenuous, to wedding, and similarly Hochmut, to pride or esteem. Both (somewhat) to hoch, but not to each other.

Comment: Its only from the 17. Century that [*"Hochzeit"*](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Hochzeit) is used for a wedding, which is the exclusive meaning in modern German. Before that any high ranked feast was a *"hōchgezīt"*. Note the common etymology with Old English *"hēahtīd"*.

Answer (score 4):

Not only that they do not have a connection in context, no, you do not even pronounce the prefixes the same way, despite the fact both are spelled the same.

In 'Hochmut' you would rather accent the 'o' like 'Hoooochmut' and in 'Hochzeit' you would accent the 'o' less, so that the 'ch' is emphasized.

But that's only a subtle difference.

Comment: "you do not even pronounce the prefixes the same way, despite the fact both are spelled the same." That's good to know. +1.Learning things like this is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 3):

In the spoken language "Hochzeit" (pronounching the o) and "Hochzeit" (pronouncing the ch) are different words.

- "Hochzeit" pronouncing the "ch" means exclusivly a wedding, no other implications.
- "Hochzeit" pronouncing the "o" means a time where something had a high standing, similar to "Goldene Zeit" (golden age) or "Blütezeit" (heyday). "Die Hochzeit der deutschen Kultur" could be describing a time where the german culture was very highly regarded.

The first meaning probably evolved from the second but has by itself nothing to do with the prefix "Hoch-".